# does android natively support RTP and/or SCTP?

Tags: android, sdk, rtp, sctp

I am developing a walkie-talkie application for Android, and would like to know whether RTP and/or SCTP is natively supported in the latest version of android SDK.

From whatever I have dug-up so far, the answer is no.

It seems that support for SCTP is coming in [JDK 7](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/jdk7-sctp/index.html).
But then, I am not sure how this will work with my android developemnt.

Could you please shed some light over this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't support RTP as standard you will have to use a JAVA RTP library.

Android uses a subset of the Java libraries so is not full Java with this in mind it is unlikely that the SCTP support will be implemented natively in Android

Comment: Especially since, Android is based on java 1.5 and not 1.6.

Comment: Actually this is no longer true.  Android is currently based on 1.6.